# filter based on match in vector by id

Tags: r, data.table

I am looking for a `data.table` solution to a simple problem. I have data like this:

```
library(data.table)
data <- data.table(
  id = c(1,1,2,3,3),
  code = c("A1","A3", "B1", "A2", "B2")
)
```

I wish to find the unique IDs that has a code contained in either

```
codes1 <- c("A1", "A2", "A3")
```

or

```
codes2 <- c("B1", "B2", "B3")
```

on two separate rows: Possible matches are those unique IDs with a code matching an element in `codes1` *or* `codes2` for the first row for that unique id and a code matching an element in `codes1` *or* `codes2` for the second row for that unique id (but if the code is contained in `codes1` in the first row, it has to be `codes2` in the second row, or vice versa)

So I would like to end up with this:

```
data_want <- data.table(
  id = c(1,2,3),
  match = c(0,0,1)
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We may use `%in%` with `any`

```
library(data.table)
data[, .(match = +(any(codes1 %in% code) & any(codes2 %in% code))), by = id]
```

-output

```
      id match
    <num> <int>
1:     1     0
2:     2     0
3:     3     1
```